# Return specific result from Realm Query

Tags: swift, realm

I'm using Realm to persist data entries of Animals. Each animal entry has a type, weight, and color. I'm trying to say if an animal's type is equal to monkey, then return the monkey's weight.

```
class Animal: Object {
   dynamic var type = ""
   dynamic var weight = 0.0
   dynamic var color = ""
}

let animalResults = Realm(path: Realm.defaultPath).objects(Animal)
```

I believe I need to filter & map the results, but I'm unsure how to do this with a Realm Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter method chaining to the results. If you would like to retrieve only monkey type animals, like following:

```
let monkeys = Realm().objects(Animal).filter("type == %@", "monkey")
```

If you want to collect the weight of monkeys, you can use `map` function to the results.

```
let weightOfMonkeys = map(monkeys) { $0.weight }
```